# Syntax Correct ,But Error?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file.Here is the screenshot of what i have done till now:

[image]

The first two lines runs error-free but the *third* or the *fourth line*(bordered) reports an error even though the statement is syntactically correct  and Why does it report **"invalid mode"** ?

Comment: `'c:\baby` should either be `r'c:\baby` or `'c:\\baby`.

Comment: @Blender How did the first line run then ?

Comment: Because `\d` isn't an escape sequence, but `\b` is. It worked by chance.

Comment: Just try changing '\' for '/', or use the os.path module.

Comment: that makes sense.... is r'c:\baby' is the pythonic way ?

Comment: @DiljitPR - You can use either a raw-string or a forwardslash (or even a double backslash).  The raw-string is pretty common but I personally prefer the forwardslash because it is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the filepath as `c:\baby1990.html`, but the error says it is `c:\x08aby1990.html`.

This is because the `\b` is being interpreted as an escape sequence:

```
>>> "\b"
'\x08'
>>>
```

Hence, you need to use a raw-string:

```
file=open(r"c:\baby1990.html")
```

Or, more simply, a forwardslash:

```
file=open("c:/baby1990.html")
```

Both raw-strings and escape sequences are explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).